# Comparing different types in template

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a function which will check if parameters are out of range.

I have written this:

```
template<typename X,typename Y,typename Z >
void checkParameter( X val, Y lower, Z upper)
{
    if( ( val > upper) || ( val < lower) )
    {
        log("checkParameter, val = % , lower= % , upper= %  \n", val,
                          lower,upper );
        ASSERT(false);
    }
}
```

However, when I do this

```
uint32_t var = 5000;
checkParameter( var, 0, 262143);
```

I get the warning:

```
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
```

How can I make a function which safely will handle all types?

Comment: `checkParameter(var, 0u, 262143u)` should remove the warning.

Comment: Why do you use three types instead of one ? What is a case where value's type can be differ to it's bounds ?

Comment: @borisbn it is very easy for that to happen

Comment: If you only want to get rid of the warnging something like this should do: `(val > static_cast<X>(upper)) || ( val < static_cast<X>(lower))`.

Comment: BTW, what do you expect when sign mismatch between type ?

Comment: Any ideas why this does not work with int64_t?  int64_t var = 8070450530100445183  e.g.  checkParameter( var, 0LL, 8070450530100445183LL)  When printing, var and the last value = 214783646

Answer (score 1):

As @Borisbn said you could do this like this:

```
template<typename type >
void checkParameter( type val, type lower, type upper)
{

    if( ( val > upper) || ( val < lower) )
    {
        log("checkParameter, val = % , lower= % , upper= %  \n", val,
                          lower,upper );
        ASSERT(false);
    }
}
```

## EDIT

I think you could do this like this:

```
template<bool A, bool B, bool C>
struct test {
  template < typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
  void parameters (T1, T2, T3) { /* Mismatching types */ }
};

template<>
struct test<true, true, true> { // all parameters will be signed                                                                       
  template < typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
  void parameters (T1 a, T2 b, T3 c) {
    /* do your test here */
  }
};


template<>
struct test<false, false, false> { //all parameters will be unsigned                                                                   
  template < typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
  void parameters (T1 a, T2 b, T3 c) {
    /* do your test here */
  }
};

template < typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void    testParameters(T1 a, T2 b, T3 c) {
  test<std::is_signed<T1>::value, std::is_signed<T2>::value, std::is_signed<T3>::value>::parameters(a,b,c);
}
```

Comment: This will fail to compile if the types mismatch, even when constants are passed (default int). Not fun.

Comment: Note that OP will have `error: no matching function for call to 'checkParameter(unsigned int&, int, int)'` in his given case.

Comment: I tried that but doing CheckParameter( val, 0,1), where val = uint8_t gives the error "no matching function for call to checkParameter( uint_8&, int, int).  I am changing this function but the other code still exists, which is not mine.

Comment: You could limit decution to the value only: `void checkParameter(type val, nondeduced<type> lower, nondeduced<type> upper)` with something like `template <class T> using nondeduced = T`

Comment: @CollioTV you don't need to check that *all* the integers have the same signedness; you can check the value against the lower bound and the upper bound separately.

And as my answer demonstrates, you don't *have* to do it with `class` `template`s with `bool` parameters and pass `std::is_signed`

Comment: @Angew, I'm curious, how would you do it with nondeduced? (i'm stuck at the part `unsigned is invalid for (template type)`)

Comment: @CollioTV It was wrong, it actually needs `template <class T> struct nondeduced { typedef T type; };` and parameters of type `typename nondeduced<T>::type`, [then it works](http://ideone.com/HCZYsk).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using builtin `operator <`, use a function that returns the correct result in case of sign mismatches

```
template<class A, class B>
bool lt(A a, B b)
{
    if (a < 0 && b >= 0)
        return true;
    if (a >= 0 && b < 0)
        return false;
    return a < b;
}
```

You'll still get warnings, so you'll probably also want some `#pragma GCC diagnostic push; ignored; pop` around it.

Comment: Instead of a compiler-specific pragma, you could solve this by `static_cast`ing the `0`s to the appropriate `A` or `B` type.

Comment: @Angew No, those won't warn for sign-compare. They will warn about "comparison is always true" though, and the final `a < b` will warn about sign comparison.

Answer (score 1):

As a combination of o11c's and Ajay's answers, you can use this comparison function which doesn't produce any warnings:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
bool lt(A a, B b) {
    if (a < 0 && b >= 0)
        return true;
    if (a >= 0 && b < 0)
        return false;
    using TYPE = decltype(a + b);
    return static_cast<TYPE>(a) < static_cast<TYPE>(b);
}
```

It works with any combination of signed and unsigned numeric types.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ced022bd31748a0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to deduce what is the biggest types amongst three. You may use this approach:

```
template<typename X, typename Y, typename Z >
void checkParameter(X val, Y lower, Z upper)
{
    using TYPE = decltype(val + lower + upper);
    if (((TYPE) val > (TYPE) upper) || ((TYPE) val < (TYPE)lower))
    { 
        ASSERT(false);
    }
}
```

Your compiler should be supporting `decltype` as well as this `using` construct.

Comment: This will fail horribly when mixing unsigned and signed numbers.

Comment: Consider `checkParameter(std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), 0u, std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max());`

Comment: @o11c, that's a valid point. Have another assert that checks no negatives are passed to it.